# Yii2 multi captcha in one page

Tags: yii2, captcha

I have a page that contains multi captcha in separated forms form example login and register modals , etc.
if I use below codes the problem is that when refresh one captcha then another captcha will be unusable because they use same session varible:

1) Login

login modal (view):

```
echo Captcha::widget([
    'id' => 'Login-captcha',
    'name' => 'LoginModel[captcha]',
    'captchaAction' => '/site/captcha'
]);
```

LoginModel :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [              
        ['captcha', 'captcha'],
    ];
}
```

2) Register

register modal (view):

```
echo Captcha::widget([
    'id' => 'register-captcha',
    'name' => 'RegisterModel[captcha]',
    'captchaAction' => '/site/captcha'
]);
```

RegisterModel:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [              
        ['captcha', 'captcha'],
    ];
}
```

to solve session problem I used different captcha actions to set different session variables:

1)Login

login modal view:

```
echo Captcha::widget([
    'id' => 'Login-captcha',
    'name' => 'LoginModel[captcha]',
    'captchaAction' => '/site/captcha-login'
]);
```

LoginModel :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [              
        ['captcha', 'captcha', 'captchaAction' => 'site/captcha-login',],
    ];
}
```

2) Register

register modal (view):

```
echo Captcha::widget([
    'id' => 'register-captcha',
    'name' => 'RegisterModel[captcha]',
    'captchaAction' => '/site/captcha-register'
]);
```

RegisterModel:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [              
        ['captcha', 'captcha', 'captchaAction' => 'site/captcha-register',],
    ];
}
```

until now everything is ok but when I move sessions from regular php files to database by below config in commponent section of main config file:

```
'session' => [
     'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
 ],
```

then captchas in the first page load not works and have to refresh them to work correctly.
what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is for yii1 but you can get the idea, more [detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/28844-two-captchas-on-the-same-page/)

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        ...
        array('verifyCode1', 'captcha', ...
        array('verifyCode2', 'verifycaptcha2', ...
    );
}

public function verifycaptcha2($attribute, $params)
{
        $captcha2 = Yii::app()->getController()->createAction('captcha2nd');
        if (!$captcha2->validate($this->verifyCode2, false))
        {
                $this->addError('verifyCode2', 'invalid captcha.');
        }
}
```

Also see [this](http://yii2-user.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/adding-captcha.html)